# Drawing boundary of shape entirely inside the shape in PDF

Tags: pdf, boundary

I am using Path Construction in PDF to draw a shape, say a rectangle. For example:

> 0  0  m 0 1 l 1 1 l 1 0 l 0 0 l B

But now, the line connecting (0,0) and (0,1) has (0,0) and (0,1) in the center. Therefore, the boundary "leaves" the rectangle by half of the line width.

Is there a parameter, so that the boundary is drawn entirely inside the rectangle?

Comment: Use a clip path the size of that rectangle.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you see and clearly indicate what you think is wrong.

Comment: That is a very small rectangle. Since the default line width is 1 anyway, have you tried just drawing a larger rectangle? Also, unless your MediaBox and CropBox are non-default, then the left and bottom edges of your stroked rectangle are cut off.  Say "72 72 m 72 82 l 82 82 l 82 72 l 72 72 l B"

Comment: You could also be running a foul of winding rules. Try "B*" instead of "B" to switch from non-zero to even-odd winding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, *using a clip path the size of that rectangle* is an option.

As your path only consists of the rectangle in question, you can do so very easily, simply add the clipping path operator **W** before the path painting operator **B**:

```
0 0 m 0 1 l 1 1 l 1 0 l 0 0 l W B
```

If you don't want to keep the clip path, enclose all this in save-state/restore-state

```
q
0 0 m 0 1 l 1 1 l 1 0 l 0 0 l W B
Q
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just the normal behaviour of the line drawing operation.

The thickness of the line is spread equally to both sides of the line. So if you have a 10pt think line from (0,0) to (10,0) and use the butt cap line style, you will have a filled rectangular area with the corners (0,-5), (10,-5), (10,5), (0,5).

Have a look at [this PDF file](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/examples/graphics.pdf) - you can see this effect in the second row, second column. The inner white lines and the outer black lines have the same start and end points.

So if you want to have everything inside that rectangle, either using a clip path like mkl said or calculate the necessary end points, taking the line width and line cap/join style into account.